# javascript - Login function does not allow user to log in, or alert for invalid credentials

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

The code for the log in function should check for a match with the credentials that were entered, or alert the user that they entered invalid credentials. My code does neither, when i click the button, it doesnt work. Please let me know if i have made an error that i do not see. Thanks!
LOGIN CODE:

```js
function addEvent() {
    var snumber = document.getElementById('snumberE').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('passE').value;
    var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profiles'));
    for(var i=0; i<arr.lenght; i++) {
        if(arr[i].password == pass && arr[i].snumber == snumber) {
            window.open('StudentView.html');
        } else {
            alert('Please enter valid credentials or sign up');
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Page</title>
        <script src='Login.js'></script>
        <style>
            #form1 {
                    position: relative;
                    float: left;
                    width: 600px;
            }
            #form2 {
                position: relative;
                float: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 id=tru>Announcement App</h1> 
<!--Navigation Bar-->
        <ul> 
           <a href="Login%20Page.html"><li>Login</li></a>
          <a href="SignUpPage.html"><li>Sign Up</li></a>
            <li>Help</li>
        </ul>
        <fieldset id=form1>
            <h2>Student Login</h2>
            <form>
            Student Number:
            <input required id="snumberE" type="text"  placeholder="Enter Student #"><br>
            Password:
            <input required id="passE" type="password"  placeholder="Enter Password"><br>
            <input type="submit" onclick='addEvent()' value='Login'>
            </form>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

SIGNUP CODE

```js
function clubslist() {
    var clublist = document.getElementById('clubs');
    var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('clublist'))
    for(i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text= arr[i];
        option.value = arr[i]
        clublist.add(option,clublist.options[null]);
    }     
}
function SignUp() {
    var list = document.getElementById('clubs');
    var selected = [];
    var profiles = [];
    var profile = {
        fname: document.getElementById('firstname').value,
        lname: document.getElementById('lastname').value,
        snumber: document.getElementById('snumber').value,
        gender: document.getElementById('gender').value,
        grade: document.getElementById('grade').value,
        clubs: selected,
        password: document.getElementById('password').value,
        rpassword: document.getElementById('1password').value
    };
    profiles.push(profile);
    if(localStorage.getItem('profiles') == null) {
        localStorage.setItem('profiles',JSON.stringify(profiles));        
    } else {
        var pfiles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profiles'));
        pfiles.push(profile);
        localStorage.setItem('profiles', JSON.stringify(pfiles));
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>Sign Up Page</title>
        <script src='Signup.js'></script>
        <style>
            #field1 {
                position: relative;
                float: left;
                width: 300px;
            }
            #field2 {
                position: relative;
                float: center;
                width: 300px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload = 'clubslist()'>
        <h1>Announcement App</h1>
<!--Navigation Bar-->
    <ul>
    <a href="Login%20Page.html"><li>Login</li></a>
          <a href="SignUpPage.html"><li>Sign Up</li></a>
    <li>Help</li>
    </ul>
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <fieldset id=field1>
            <h3>Student Sign Up</h3>
            <form tag="signupinfo">
                First Name:
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" id="firstname" required><br>
                Last Name:
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" id="lastname" required><br>
                Student Number:
                <input id="snumber" type="text" placeholder="Enter Student Number" name="studentnumber" required><br>
                Gender:
                    <select id=gender required>
                        <option value=male>Male</option>
                        <option value=female>Female</option>
                    </select><br>
                Grade:
                    <select id=grade name="grade" required>
                        <option value="9">Grade 9</option>
                        <option value="10">Grade 10</option>
                        <option value="11">Grade 11</option>
                        <option value="12">Grade 12</option>
                    </select><br>
                Clubs:<br>
                    <select id=clubs multiple></select><br>
                Password:
                <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required><br>
                Repeat Password:
                <input id="1password" type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required><br>
                <button type="submit" onclick="SignUp()" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you thought about using ajax and a server-side language... this doesn't seem like a secure login, just a post of data from one page to another which removes the point of a login.... to ensure that person is who they claim to be and are authorised to access anything from that....Also you need to prevent the form from submitting if you want to run javascript.

Comment: This is actually for a school project so its only for the purpose of getting used to the language. I'm not sure if i can use another language. Also, how can i prevent the form from submitting?

Comment: Okay, well server-side will  require a server to run it on and since this is for school it's no doubt out of the question. To use javascript to prevent default actions maybe this will help you https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: In your clubslist() function array.length is spelt incorrectly. This will prevent your code working.

Comment: it's supposed to be arr.length, because arr is the variable name.